# Чтение нового сообщение, и сохранение его в новую переменную.TelegramBot

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, telegram

Как обработать новое сообщение от пользователя?

```
Console.WriteLine($"Received a '{messageText}' message in chat {chatId}.");
if (message.Text == "/start")
{
    Message sent = await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync
    (
    chatId: chatId,
    messageText = "Бот начал работу",
    cancellationToken: cancellationToken


    );
 
}
foreach (var item in database)
{
    if (messageText == item.AnalisisName)//тут
    {

        Message sent = await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(
        chatId: chatId,
        text: "Введите цену",
        parseMode: ParseMode.MarkdownV2,
        disableNotification: true,
        replyToMessageId: update.Message.MessageId,
        cancellationToken: cancellationToken

        );

    }
    var mes = message.Text;  // и тут
```